# How to hide tabbar for some pages and make it visible again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I've got an application that uses a Tab Bar Controller along with a Navigation Controller.But for some pages I want to hide both bars(Tab & navigation) after that those will be visible again...I am able to hide navigation bar & also done with making. it appear after some pages.
 I am able to hide tab bar with
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed{
 return TRUE;
}

But problem is how do I make it Visible again after some pages?

Comment: You may want to accept answers for your other questions first.

Answer (score 6):

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) animated:YES];
```

then in a subclassed UITabBarController

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(BOOL)hide animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (tabBarHidden == hide) { return; }

    if (animated) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    }

    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {

            if (!hide) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y-49, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y+49, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
        } else {
            if (!hide) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height-49)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height+49)];
            }

        }
    }

    if (animated) { [UIView commitAnimations]; }

    tabBarHidden = hide;

}
```

Comment: make sure you subclass a UITabBarController and include this method within it

Comment: Can you be more specific? This code was copied straight out of where I am using it in my code, where it works. Obviously you need to declare tabBarHidden outside of the scope of this method.

Comment: @adam - thanks for adding this, this works perfectly for me. Can you explain me what are the subviews of the tabbar? I noticed in the code, you are taking the tabbars subviews and shrinking them down to 0 pixels when it's hidden. If I don't do this, then it leaves that white space there even if the tabbar is hidden. It works for me, but can you explain why that is?